# What is the best way to do AppEngine Model Memcaching?

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached, google-cloud-datastore

Currently my application caches models in memcache like this:

```
memcache.set("somekey", aModel)
```

But Nicks' post at http://blog.notdot.net/2009/9/Efficient-model-memcaching suggests that first converting it to protobuffers is a lot more efficient. But after running some tests I found out it's indeed smaller in size, but actually *slower* (~10%).

Do others have the same experience or am I doing something wrong?

Test results: http://1.latest.sofatest.appspot.com/?times=1000

```
import pickle
import time
import uuid

from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import util
from google.appengine.datastore import entity_pb
from google.appengine.api import memcache

class Person(db.Model):
 name = db.StringProperty()

times = 10000

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):

 def get(self):

  self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/plain'

  m = Person(name='Koen Bok')

  t1 = time.time()

  for i in xrange(int(self.request.get('times', 1))):
   key = uuid.uuid4().hex
   memcache.set(key, m)
   r = memcache.get(key)

  self.response.out.write('Pickle took: %.2f' % (time.time() - t1))


  t1 = time.time()

  for i in xrange(int(self.request.get('times', 1))):
   key = uuid.uuid4().hex
   memcache.set(key, db.model_to_protobuf(m).Encode())
   r = db.model_from_protobuf(entity_pb.EntityProto(memcache.get(key)))


  self.response.out.write('Proto took: %.2f' % (time.time() - t1))


def main():
 application = webapp.WSGIApplication([('/', MainHandler)], debug=True)
 util.run_wsgi_app(application)


if __name__ == '__main__':
 main()
```

Comment: I just tried it with really large and complex models too, but the result was about the same.

Comment: Maybe there is http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html on GAE? This should show more accurate results, but still - after reading the blog entry you linked to I would expect order of magnitude difference between performance of protobuffers and pickle - and this should be catched by time.time() anyway..

Comment: i'm using java appengine, so I'm too lazy to test this theory - is pickle() caching the results behind the scenes somewhere, whereas to_protobuf is not?  Based on the article, i'm not sure i would expect a full order of magnitude increase in speed, as pickle is still being called even using the protobuf version.  the space used could certainly be vastly smaller though.

Comment: I did some more tests, and memcache only pickles non-strings, so storing a single model will not pickle at all, and a list of models will be pickled as a list with strings.

Comment: This is certainly a surprising result. I would say that it's a dev_appserver phenomena, but you're seeing the same results on appspot. Color me confused - this certainly didn't used to be the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Memcache call still pickles the object with or without using protobuf. Pickle is faster with a protobuf object since it has a very simple model

Plain pickle objects are larger than protobuf+pickle objects, hence they save time on Memcache, but there is more processor time in doing the protobuf conversion

Therefore in general either method works out about the same...but

The reason you should use protobuf is it can handle changes between versions of the models, whereas Pickle will error. This problem will bite you one day, so best to handle it sooner

Comment: Although some good points are made, but not everything stated is true. If you look at the code the memcache api only pickles non-strings. So lists with protobuffed models will be pickled, single models not. Indeed protobufs output is simpler and smaller, my tests suggest it's not less cpu intensive - hence the original question. The model versions point is valid, but not too important to me as you should have a way of dealing with invalid cache results anyway and it won't happen very often I presume.

Answer (score 1):

Both pickle and protobufs are slow in App Engine since they're implemented in pure Python. I've found that writing my own, simple serialization code using methods like str.join tends to be faster since most of the work is done in C. But that only works for simple datatypes.

Comment: Did you do this for model objects too? I would be curious to see your implementation.

Comment: I used to do this, but python2.7 gives us cpickle and it's now faster.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it more quickly is to turn your model into a dictionary and use the native eval / repr function as your (de)serializers -- with caution of course, as always with the evil eval, but it should be safe here given that there is no external step.

Below an example of a class Fake_entity implementing exactly that.
You first create your dictionary through `fake = Fake_entity(entity)` then you can simply store your data via `memcache.set(key, fake.serialize())`. The serialize() is a simple call to the native dictionary method of repr, with some additions if you need (e.g. add an identifier at the beginning of the string).

To fetch it back, simply use `fake = Fake_entity(memcache.get(key))`. The Fake_entity object is a simple dictionary whose keys are also accessible as attributes. You can access your entity properties normally, except referenceProperties give keys instead of fetching the object (which is actually quite useful). You can also get() the actual entity with fake.get(), or more interestigly, change it and then save with fake.put().

It does not work with lists (if you fetch multiple entities from a query), but could be easily be adjusted with join/split functions using an identifier like '### FAKE MODEL ENTITY ###' as the separator. Use with db.Model only, would need small adjustments for Expando.

```
class Fake_entity(dict):
    def __init__(self, record):
        # simple case: a string, we eval it to rebuild our fake entity
        if isinstance(record, basestring):
            import datetime # <----- put all relevant eval imports here
            from google.appengine.api import datastore_types
            self.update( eval(record) ) # careful with external sources, eval is evil
            return None

        # serious case: we build the instance from the actual entity
        for prop_name, prop_ref in record.__class__.properties().items():
            self[prop_name] = prop_ref.get_value_for_datastore(record) # to avoid fetching entities
        self['_cls'] = record.__class__.__module__ + '.' + record.__class__.__name__
        try:
            self['key'] = str(record.key())
        except Exception: # the key may not exist if the entity has not been stored
            pass

    def __getattr__(self, k):
        return self[k]

    def __setattr__(self, k, v):
        self[k] = v

    def key(self):
        from google.appengine.ext import db
        return db.Key(self['key'])

    def get(self):
        from google.appengine.ext import db
        return db.get(self['key'])

    def put(self):
        _cls = self.pop('_cls') # gets and removes the class name form the passed arguments
        # import xxxxxxx ---> put your model imports here if necessary
        Cls = eval(_cls) # make sure that your models declarations are in the scope here
        real_entity = Cls(**self) # creates the entity
        real_entity.put() # self explanatory
        self['_cls'] = _cls # puts back the class name afterwards
        return real_entity

    def serialize(self):
        return '### FAKE MODEL ENTITY ###\n' + repr(self)
        # or simply repr, but I use the initial identifier to test and eval directly when getting from memcache
```

I would welcome speed tests on this, I would assume this is quite faster than the other approaches. Plus, you do not have any risks if your models have changed somehow in the meantime.

Below an example of what the serialized fake entity looks like. Take a particular look at datetime (created) as well as reference properties (subdomain) :

### FAKE MODEL ENTITY ###
{'status': u'admin', 'session_expiry': None, 'first_name': u'Louis', 'last_name': u'Le Sieur', 'modified_by': None, 'password_hash': u'a9993e364706816aba3e25717000000000000000', 'language': u'fr', 'created': datetime.datetime(2010, 7, 18, 21, 50, 11, 750000), 'modified': None, 'created_by': None, 'email': u'chou@glou.bou', 'key': 'agdqZXJlZ2xlcgwLEgVMb2dpbhjmAQw', 'session_ref': None, '_cls': 'models.Login', 'groups': [], 'email___password_hash': u'chou@glou.bou+a9993e364706816aba3e25717000000000000000', 'subdomain': datastore_types.Key.from_path(u'Subdomain', 229L, _app=u'jeregle'), 'permitted': [], 'permissions': []}

Personally I also use static variables (faster than memcache) to cache my entities in the short term, and fetch the datastore when the server has changed or its memory has been flushed for some reason (which happens quite often in fact).